# Loop frame case study

Tags: ethernet

Peter Paluch did an [experiment](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10816351/whats-loop-traffic-ethereal) regarding loop frame. However I do not understand the connection/cabling on that experiment. Refer statement below.

> The switch under test was connected via Fa0/1 to a hub (for sniffing
>   purposes) and the hub was subsequently connected to another switch
>   whose other two ports were intentionally connected together, creating
>   a loop.

This maybe the answer to [my question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/ethernet-keepalive-test-l2-functionality-and-detect-network-loop-switch) if I can understand the connection/cabling that he made.

Comment: Please clarify what Peter Paluch experiment you're referring to. I don't see one mentioned in the hyperlink in the first sentence

Comment: @MikePennington I have corrected the link.